# Magento2 : checkbox change function in knockout js

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I need to add one checkbox on checkout and call one function on checkbox change event, how can I do that?

Check this screenshot for better understanding exactly what I need.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more info please, does this need to be within an existing UI component or in a custom one? How much UI component/KO do you know? If you already know how to work with both this is how - `data-bind="checked: yourFunction"` See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html

Comment: Yes, that i check but i need proper way to call this function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, i found a solution for checkbox change event.

I have added this checkbox on shipping method section so the html checkbox available on this path.

```
/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/shipping/custom.html


<input type="checkbox" name="custom" value="custom-fee" data-bind='checked: CheckVal'/>
```

Now, CheckVal  function created in the knockout model file, for me it's available here,

```
/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/shipping/custom.js
```

And the code for checked or unchecked event is,

```
return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Namespace_Mymodule/checkout/shipping/custom'
        },
        initObservable: function () {

            this._super()
                .observe({
                    CheckVal: ko.observable(true)                        
                });

            this.CheckVal.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                if(newValue){
                    console.log('checked');
                }else{
                    console.log('Unchecked');
                }
            });

            return this;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have tried your answer. The event is working fine. But the checkbox is selected by default onpageload when i use the data-bind. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Getting error ReferenceError: CheckVal is not defined

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
  onCheckedChanged: function () {
            // do something
        }
```

in your js component

> vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/single-checkbox.js